# Keeping steps in sync of long running process and creating common layer for code repitition

Tags: c#

I have 1 long running process wrapped inside a method and it is for 2 different types like below :

- Type1
- Type2

Code :

```
public interface IBaseType
    {
        MyResult LongRunningProcess(int noOfTimes); //doenst save long running process data in database.just returns the results to consumer
        void LongRunningProcess(int noOfTimes); //Save results of long running process in database.Background job with on-demand as well as scheduled
    }

public class Type1 : IBaseType
{
    public void LongRunningProcess(int noOfTimes)
        {
           //Step1 : 
           for (int i = 0; i < noOfTimes; i++)
               {
             //Create connection with database.
             //Do some processing based on type1
             //Save results of those processing
            }

        //Step2:
        // Creating versioning here  : If this failed then rollback step1

            //Step3 : if step1 and step2 successfull than mark this job as succeeded else failed
        // Updating time of whole process in table
    }
 }




 public class Type2 : IBaseType
   {
        public void LongRunningProcess(int noOfTimes)
            {
               //Step1 : 
               for (int i = 0; i < noOfTimes; i++)
                   {
                 //Create connection with database.
                 //Do some processing based on type2
                 //Save results of those processing
                }

            //Step2:
            // Creating versioning here  : If this failed then rollback step1

                //Step3 : if step1 and step2 successfull than mark this job as succeeded else failed
            // Updating time of whole process in table
        }
   }
```

So as you can see here that Step2 and Step3 code are getting repeated for both the types so i want to avoid step2 and step3 code repetition for both the types.

Secondly I want to keep step1 and step2 in sync so that step 2 failed then rollback whole step1 process whatever has been done inside it.

I am bit confused with moving versioning in base abstract class because that would probably tightly coupled it with this long running process.I want to design it in a way that tomorrow if i think of removing versioning then it should not hamper my current design and code.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Downvoters and close voters could you please tell me what is wrong with this question?Please care to comment and not just come here do random downvoting/close voting and go away :)

Answer (score 2):

You could apply the [template design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) here.

You will have an abstract class, with the shared code or algorithm (which is the same for both your types). And each of the types should implement the specific part of the algorithm - the processing part.

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public abstract void Process();

    // The "Template method"
    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //Create connection with database.
            Process();
            //Save results of those processing
        }

    //Step2:
    // Creating versioning here  : If this failed then rollback step1

    //Step3 : if step1 and step2 successfull than mark this job as succeeded else failed
    // Updating time of whole process in table
    }
}

class Type1 : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Process()
    {
       //Do some processing based on type1
    } 
}

class Type2 : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Process()
    {
        //Do some processing based on type2
    }
}
```

In order to separate versioning logic, inject the logic to the class, as follows, the versioning done before saveing to db, so only if it succeeds, you actually do the save. If it is not the case for you and you need to do the versioning after writing to db, check the connector you use for writing to db, it should have some way to use [db transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) (which allows you to commit or rollback your changes after checking that constraints are met).

abstract class AbstractClass
    {
        private readonly IVersionInterface _versionCreator;

```
    protected AbstractClass(IVersionInterface versionCreator)
    {
        _versionCreator = versionCreator;
    }

    public abstract void Process();

    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        var versionCreated = _versionCreator.CreateVersion();
        if (!versionCreated)
        {
          return;
        }

       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           //Create connection with database.
           Process();
          //Save results of those processing
      }

      //Step3 : if step1 and step2 successful than mark this job as 
     //succeeded else failed
     // Updating time of whole process in table
    }
}

class Type1 : AbstractClass
{

    public Type1(IVersionInterface versionCreator) : 
base(versionCreator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process()
    {
        //Do some processing based on type1
    }
}

class Type2 : AbstractClass
{

    public Type2(IVersionInterface versionCreator) : 
base(versionCreator)
    {
    }

    public override void Process()
    {
        //Do some processing based on type2
    }
}  

interface IVersionInterface
{
    bool CreateVersion();
}

class VersionCreator : IVersionInterface
{
    //return true or false for success or failure
    public bool CreateVersion()
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but then how do i keep step1 and step2 in sync?

Comment: What do you mean keep to steps in sync? If you mean how to do rollback for each type, you can add specific implementation in the deriving classes (add another abstract method similar to Process)

Comment: So lets say my loop inside LongRunningProcess method have run for 3 times and save some results in database.Now lets say there was some error creating versioning then how do i rollback all those things that happened in loop?

Comment: So you will have to implement this logic, if it is common, implement it in the Abstract class, or if it is specific each of the derived will have it's own logic. Can you create versioning before making changes to DB, and only if succeeded, save the data. also you may consider using transaction when inserting to DB, which allows you to rollback or commit you changes if some condition is met.

Comment: Both Type 1 and Type2 share same algorithm for versioning creation and also putting it in abstract class will tightly coupled because what if i dont want verissioning tomorrow then?

Comment: That is true, seems that it is a different responsibility, so it shouldn't be part of this class. Just implement this logic in some other class, and pass it as interface so you can pass any implementation to the abstract class. This way you separate responsibilities and allow different implementations for the versioning, including empty implementation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187853/discussion-between-mr-bean-and-lena-kaplan).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class to manage process running with Func as a constructor parameter. This would give the flexibility to use functions with different parameters with different results.

Example:

```
public class LongProcessRunner<T>
{
    private Func<T> longProcess;

    public LongProcessRunner(Func<T> longProcess)
    {
        this.longProcess = longProcess;
    }

    public T RunAndReturn(int numberOfTimes)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfTimes; i++)
        {
            //connect to db
            var processResult = longProcess();
            //Save results
        }

        //versioning & rest 

        //return stuff
        var processRunner = new LongProcessRunner(() => MyFunctionWithoutParameter());

    }
}
```

So you can create this class with possible settings:

```
var processRunner = new LongProcessRunner<MyClass>(() => MyFunctionWithParameter("parameter1", "parameter2"));

var otherProcessRunner = new LongProcessRunner<MyOtherClass>(() => MyFunctionWithoutParameter());
```

So you can customize whatever you want, you can also pass `save, connect to db, versioning` logic as a constructor parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and how do i keep step1 and step2 in sync?

Comment: you can provide actions for them too(not function because recovery won't return a value), example: new LongProcessRunner<MyClass>(() => MyFunction(), myClassInstance => RecoveryFunction(myClassInstance)), with signature: LongProcessRunner(Func<T> process, Action<T> recovery);